# Linux batch rename files, with string manipulation

Tags: linux, bash, batch-processing

I have a series of folders that having this naming convention:

`DD / MM / YYYY - Name`

eg:

`01 / 05 / 2015 - test folder`

I want to convert the format for easier reading as the name is more important than the date.

I would like the output to be

`Name DD-MM-YYY`

`for i in *; do mv "$i" ...`

So how do I in the terminal, or through a .sh (bash):

- replace `/` (`\s\/\s`) with `-`?
- move the DD-MM-YYYY to the back?
- remove the `-` (`\s\-\s`)?

Comment: is the slash in the name a slash (path separator) or a literal (bad, very bad)?

Comment: `/` and the NULL character are not allowed in filenames on unix-like OS.

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ Those are not path separators, the person labelled the files as "Date" with "DD/MM/YYYY" at the front so a folder would be named "01 / 05 / 2015 - test folder" that is not a directory path.

Comment: @Drew Is `/` really slash in this naming `01 / 05 / 2015 - test folder` ? I guess no. Instead it would be something like a `division slash ` http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2215/index.htm
Otherwise your question might be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Okay hopefuly here you have a way to do it.
Probably it can be done better but it's a start point.

First, set the file name in a variable

```
file='01 / 05 / 2015 - test folder'
```

Then I used the `-` as a delimiter to grab the first part (the date) and then I changed `/` with `-`:

```
file_name=`echo $file | cut -f2 -d-`
file_date=`echo $file | cut -f1 -d- | sed 's/\//-/g'`
```

Then just set the final name:

```
mv "$file" "$file_name $file_date"
```

---

Also, if you want to delete the first space of $file_name try with

```
file_name=`echo $file | cut -f2 -d- | cut -c 2-`
```

which cut the first character of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk -F/ '{ split($3,bits,"-");var=$1"-"$2"-"bits[1];print gensub(" ","","g",bits[2])" "gensub(" ","","g",var) }'
```

Here we are splitting the data using "/" and then further split the 3rd piece of data with "-" (using the split function) We then remove the spaces where needed using the gensub function.